# Files not uploading via Aptana 3

Tags: ftp, aptana

I'm new to Aptana 3. I recently switched from using an FTP (Filezilla) and text editor just to speed the file editing process up a bit.

I'm dealing mainly with Wordpress sites on a shared Godaddy hosting account, and am having some trouble uploading the files I have edited via Aptana to my live site.

i.e. I've edited several lines in my "main.css" file. I save it in my "Project Explorer" window in Aptana, have my FTP connection all set up and working, and click the "Upload" icon. I refresh my browser and nothing has changed, and I can see the website is still pulling in the old css. I've also tried "synchronizing" my files and hitting the "Publish" button, but that doesn't work either?

I've also tried just editing the file in a new Remote Connection tab, but no joy either.

I've hunted all over for simple walkthrough for deployment or file sync guides for Aptana, and watched a few video tutorials but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

Hold <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> for a few seconds in your browser. You probably are just running a cached version of the CSS in your browser. That should prune it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What I found I had to do was an initial synchronization, I know you mention that you did this but it may be that it didn't fully sync as its not always clear what is going on with the Aptana sync.

What I did:

1. Make sure your Project has a connection in it and that it points to the server location that you want to sync with
2. Select the Remote tab and right-click on a file within the chosen connection, choose File Transfer...
3. This will open the sync window and it will initiate a compare, this is where confusion set in for me, if the folder structure is not identical it will propose to create and delete lots of files.  I found I was deselecting items to be safe but meant that it did not correctly sync.  Make sure you are syncing from the same root level and then let it do a full sync, this seems to register or record a link between the local and remote files.
4. Run the sync.  when it is complete you will now be able to upload individual files successfully from the Project tab using the upload icon (before a successful sync this will not work - even though it looks like it is doing an upload).

Hope this helps.